# Visual studio 2017 load project failed

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, project

Yesterday, I have finished working on my **Android** project (c# and Xamarin) on Visual Studio 2017, I closed it. Today, I re-opened the project in order to continue my work but the project is not loading, plus, I am getting an error in the output window saying:

> There is a missing project subtype.
>   Subtype: '{EFBA0AD7-5A72-4C68-AF49-83D382785DCF}' is unsupported by this installation.

I have searched up and tried every solution online but nothing worked for me. I tried to delete `.suo file`, repairing vs.. I do not know what to do.. please help me to solve my problem.

**Here's a screenshot of the error**

[image]

**UPDATE**
I enabled Xamarin for Visual Studio, now the error in the output window is (and the project is still failing to load):

```
[I:]:                     Found Xamarin.Android 8.0.0.33
[I:sdk]:                  Runtime path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android
[I:sdk]:                  Framework path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Xamarin\VisualStudio\15.0_6c165955\Android\AndroidSdkDirectory found:
    Path contains adb in \platform-tools (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk).
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Xamarin\VisualStudio\15.0_6c165955\Android\AndroidNdkDirectory found:
    Path contains ndk-stack in \. (C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r13b).
[I:sdk]:                    Key HKCU\SOFTWARE\Xamarin\VisualStudio\15.0_6c165955\Android\JavaSdkDirectory found:
    Path contains jarsigner.exe in \bin (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131).
[I:]:                     Found Android SDK. API levels: 22, 23, 24, 25
```

Comment: what kind of project is it ? winform, asp , wpf, uwp ? why did you tag `android` ? is it a XAMARIN project ?

Comment: `EFBA0AD7-5A72-4C68-AF49-83D382785DCF` : That is an `Xamarin.Android` project type, ensure that the Xamarin component is installed in your VS installation

Comment: @zackraiyan It is Android

Comment: can you try my solution and see if it works ?

Comment: @SushiHangover I enabled Xamarin. Would you see my update ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never worked with `XAMARIN` before but faced somewhat similar situations with other projects. Here's what you can do :

**1. Create a new project**

**2. Right click on project > Add > Existing Item**

**3. Browse to the previous projects directory and add all the project files(i mean code files such as .cs)**

**4. In winforms, if you add back a form's .cs file, it should automatically load the .designer.cs as well. **

After doing so, you can get back the entire project. There might be a few errors but they are easily fixable.
Hope this helps :)

Comment: That's a hard approach. My project is very big with more than 5 activities and classes. I prefer a more practical way and would like to know what is causing the error in the first place.

Comment: Hmm...i personally believe there's no other way because there was a time when i spent days behind fixing my broken project....and what do you mean by `hard approach` ? you easily copy paste all files in the new project folder, in `Solution explorer` make sure to click show all files, Select all files with CTRL+A and right click > Include in project , that takes roughly a minute :)

Comment: Umm, that doesn't seem like much of a work to me... however, if you ever find a better solution to this, make sure to share your answer :)

Comment: Okay, it worked, it took one hour :) But I am curious about what was causing this error for the next time.

Comment: @Wassim01 , see i told ya :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a global.json with and sdk for dotnet core that wasn't installed.

Either install the targeted version or update your global.json to fit what you have installed.